# Jquery fadeOut one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to give `item_div` inside `container_div` `fadeOut` one by one. And I tried this code , it `fadeOut` all together, is that anything that I can improve or any suggestion can do that?

```js
$(".container_div .item_div").each(function(idx){
  $(this).delay(100*idx).fadeOut(3000);
});
```

```css
.container_div{
  background:#ccc;
  }
.item_div{
  background:#454545;
  color:#fff;
  margin:5px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container_div">
  <div class="item_div">1</div>
  <div class="item_div">2</div>
  <div class="item_div">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".container_div .item_div").each(function(idx,item){
    setTimeout(function(){ $(item).fadeOut(1000); }, (idx+1)*1000);
});
```

This works fine here   [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ckqwdm28/)